# Ruby on Rails 4 scope lasts 5 record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to make a scope to get the last 5 records in Rails 4, but I have problems with syntax. Here is what I've managed to do:

`scope :news, last(5).reverse`

`scope :most_recent, -> { order(created_at: :desc).limit(10) }`

But it doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

try

`scope :most_recent, -> { order("created_at DESC").limit(5) }`